# Is it possible to die while wearing the Cloak of Invisibility?

Tags: harry-potter

At the end of *Tale of the Three Brothers*, it reads:

> But though Death searched for the third brother for many years, he was never able to find him. It was only when he had attained a great age that the youngest brother finally took off the Cloak of Invisibility and gave it to his son.

From this passage, can we infer that you cannot die while wearing the Cloak?

Comment: No, you can't infer that.

Comment: It is only a tale where the death is personified. It is metaphorical story.

Comment: malfoy hit's harry with the full body bind curse while he's under the cloak

Comment: @padfoot but he didn't kill him

Comment: i think that that's irrelevant, the spell still ***worked***